# How to prevent section from scrolling when dragging cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want sections would have same behavior as cells when I drag it.
Usual behavior is — when dragging cells, section stands on a same place until it meets other section.
What I want is section drags as usual cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is from the **UITableView Class Reference**

> Table views can have one of two styles, UITableViewStylePlain and
>   UITableViewStyleGrouped. When you create a UITableView instance you
>   must specify a table style, and this style cannot be changed. In the
>   plain style, section headers and footers float above the content if
>   the part of a complete section is visible.

If you are going to use the UITableViewStylePlain, I am not sure you can re-engineer the section headers to not float.

An alternative is to use the UITableViewStyleGrouped or use UITableViewStylePlain and instead of using sections, you could separate out your table view by placing the section as another cell.